# Why am I not able to edit the privileges for 'openrevenue' and 'opendeals' in Field Level Security in CRM 2015?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

opendeals and openrevenue are the two OOB fields on Account in CRM 2015 Online. Field level security is turned on by default for these fields.

However, I'm not able to edit Update and Create privileges on these fields in Field Level Security. The drop-down to assign the right privilege is deactivated?

Is this a known issue or is it supposed to be this way?

Answer (score 0):

That's because they are [rollup fields (MSDN ref)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn817863.aspx#BKMK_Rollup), which are handled by the system itself.

> Rollup attributes
>
> Because rollup attributes persist in the database, they can be used for filtering or sorting just like regular attributes. Any kind of process or plug-in will use the most recently calculated value of the attribute. *Rollup attribute values are calculated asynchronously by scheduled system jobs*. Administrators set when a job is run or pause the job. By default, each attribute is updated hourly.
>
> When a rollup attribute is created or updated a Mass Calculated Rollup Fields job is scheduled to run in 12 hours. The 12-hour delay is intended to perform this resource intensive operation during a time that will affect users the least. After the job completes, the next time it is scheduled to run will be 10 years in the future. If there is a problem with the calculation, this will be reported with the system job.
>
> Locate the system job in Settings > System Jobs to find any errors with rollup fields.

Comment: Hi Alex,

Infact, I have a plugin that updates a few currency fields on the Account. However, none of my code deals with updating any of these fields.

So when anyone who is not a Sys Admin, who tries to update the other currency records from a Quote on the Parent Account, they get an error saying that the openrevenue and opendeals can't be updated.

Whereas, I'm not even touching any of these fields using the code. Kindly advise.
thanks.

Comment: That comment should be a new question

Comment: We had the same problem as described in @priyeshwagh777's comment - we "fixed" it by disabling field security for the "openrevenue" field.